# How to keep hash in redirect url Laravel 8 and Inertiajs

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-8, inertiajs

I am using Laravel 8 with Inertiajs and React. I'm trying to redirect to a url with a hash on the end of the url, and for some reason no matter how I construct the url, Laravel is stripping the fragment at the end. Even when I explicitly use `withFragment`, it doesn't work. Here's my controller:

```php
    /**
     * Handle request to store a new answer
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $question = Question::find($request->input('question')['id']);
        $questionAuthor = User::find($question->user_id);
        $answer = $request->input('answer');

        $newAnswer = new Answer; 
        $newAnswer->body = $answer['body'];
        $newAnswer->user_id = $userId;
        $newAnswer->question_id = $question->id;
        $newAnswer->save();

        Mail::to($questionAuthor)->send(new NewAnswer(
            $questionAuthor, 
            $newAnswer,
            $question
        ));

        $url = url("/questions/{$question->slug}");

        return redirect($url)->withFragment($newAnswer->id);
    }
```

If someone could help me understand why the hash is being stripped from the end and how I might fix it, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Try `redirect()->to($url)->withFragment($newAnswer->id)`? That's how I usually do it. Though you really shouldn't be hard-coding URLs but instead using route names. Your code should ideally look more like `redirect()->route("question", $question)->withFragment($newAnswer->id);`

Comment: Thanks @miken32 I'm going to try your suggestion. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The hash is still being stripped off the end. Totally confused and frustrated

Comment: I assume you've done the debugging to confirm that you're passing valid values? And, another suggestion. You should be using route model binding wherever you can, to let Laravel do model lookups and handle cases where models aren't found. What happens in your method above if `$question` is null because no matching record was found?

Comment: Yes. And it doesn't matter what I pass for the fragment whether its dynamically generated or hard-coded. Just gets stripped off. That's a bit of a separate issue. This project is still a ways from being done. Proper error handling will come

Comment: Well I'd suggest you're making some kind of mistake somewhere along the way; redirection with a fragment is certainly something that works just fine. Try `$r = redirect($url)->withFragment($newAnswer->id); dd($r->getTargetUrl());` and see what it returns.

Comment: So that does show that the hash is being appended. But if I do the same with the current url in the controller for the route being redirected to, the hash has been stripped off. I'm not doing anything weird in that controller. I'll keep digging and see if I can figure out the reason

Comment: Check your browser's network inspector. The fragment should be part of the 301 Redirect response; if that's the case then Laravel is doing its work correctly and the problem is elsewhere.